# With StructureMap is it possible to make a Singleton object AND provide constructor arguments?

Tags: structuremap

I can't seem to figure out how to define a object as a singleton AND define two arguments for the constructor.

I can do either / or .. just not at the same time.

Eg. (this doesn't work)...

```
ForRequestedType<IFoo>()
    .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<Foo>()
    .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton)
    .WithCtorArg("alpha").EqualToAppSetting("Alpha")
    .WithCtorArg("beta").EqualToAppSetting("Beta");
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. The trick is that you need to use the alternate default DSL language **TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType**

```
ForRequestedType<IFoo>()
    .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton)
    .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Foo>()
    .WithCtorArg("alpha").EqualToAppSetting("alpha")
    .WithCtorArg("beta").EqualToAppSetting("beta");
```

Comment: You wouldn't perhaps know how to do this using the new syntax of .Use<>.For<> would you?  It seems that the syntax above is now depricated.